# Including Encog in Multicharts.Net framework

Tags: .net, runtime-error, neural-network, encog

I'm trying to use Encog library for Neural Networks in Multicharts .NET
I was simply trying to implement the XOR example to make it work in a signal, just as a first attempt to use NN in Multicharts. It shouldn't be difficoult, initialise Input and Output, and then execute the NN building, learning and running on the last bar of the charts in CalcBar() method.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using PowerLanguage.Function;
using ATCenterProxy.interop;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Encog.Neural.Networks;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Layers;
using Encog.Engine.Network.Activation;
using Encog.ML.Data;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Resilient;
using Encog.ML.Train;
using Encog.ML.Data.Basic;
using Encog;

namespace PowerLanguage.Strategy {
    public class Larning_NeuralNetwork : SignalObject {
        public Larning_NeuralNetwork(object _ctx):base(_ctx){}

        public static double[][] XORInput = {
            new[] {0.0, 0.0},
            new[] {1.0, 0.0},
            new[] {0.0, 1.0},
            new[] {1.0, 1.0}
            };

        public static double[][] XORIdeal = {
            new[] {0.0},
            new[] {1.0},
            new[] {1.0},
            new[] {0.0}
            };

        protected override void Create() {
            // create variable objects, function objects, order objects etc.
            }


        protected override void StartCalc() {
            }


        protected override void CalcBar(){

            if (Bars.LastBarOnChart){

                var network = new BasicNetwork();
                network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(null, true, 2));
                network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), true, 3));
                network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationSigmoid(), false, 1));
                network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
                network.Reset();

                // create training data
                IMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(XORInput, XORIdeal);

                // train the neural network
                IMLTrain train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);

                int epoch = 1;

                do
                {
                    train.Iteration();
                    ExpertCommentary.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Error:" + train.Error);
                    epoch++;
                } while (train.Error > 0.01);

                train.FinishTraining();

                // test the neural network
                ExpertCommentary.WriteLine(@"Neural Network Results:");
                foreach (IMLDataPair pair in trainingSet)
                {
                    IMLData output = network.Compute(pair.Input);
                    ExpertCommentary.WriteLine(pair.Input[0] + @"," + pair.Input[1]
                                      + @", actual=" + output[0] + @",ideal=" + pair.Ideal[0]);
                }

                EncogFramework.Instance.Shutdown();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I doesn't give any building error, but when running it creates a red error reporting an overflow or underflow during arithmetic operation at the line

```
network.Reset();
```

It shouldnt be the big deal, the Reset() method should just randomize the weghts of the NN matrix, how is it possible that it is not working? Any idea?